# How to keep a bash script running in the background

Tags: linux, bash

I write a simple bash script:

```
while :
do
sleep 2;

//my code

done
```

Now I want this bash script always be running.

```
bash mybash.sh > /dev/null &
```

When I run above command my bash works fine. but when I close my terminal I think my bash is killed. because it doesn't work as my script make some files when it running.

Comment: Use `nohup bash myash.sh > /dev/null &`

Comment: Or use `systemd` so it starts before you even log on... https://www.linode.com/docs/quick-answers/linux/start-service-at-boot/

Comment: use `screen` or `tmux`  and you can sleep tight...

Comment: What you want to do is to turn your script into a **daemon**. I'll let you look it up as there's plenty of documentation on the subject and it wouldn't fit into a comment but it's fairly easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

Run the script "bash script.sh"  in terminal and press ctrl+z and then use 'bg' command to put the script in background

Answer (score -1):

`#!/bin/bash`

`while true; do`

`// your code`

`sleep 5;`

`done;`

write a bash script and put it that to cron and check once it will start comment the cron it will run in a background.

insted of sleep 5 you can use whatever second you want to put.

For checking your process use below commend to get the details
`ps -ef | grep script_file_name`

if you find more then one process is running leave one process and rest kill the process for script.

Hope so this will resolve your issue....!!!!